# C# dynamically growing line graph

Tags: c#

Does anybody have a good example of a dynamically growing line graph, what i have is a program tracking users input and this input will grow varying amounts day to day but i need to graph it.  Any tips of suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: Did this ever work for what you were doing?

Answer (score 2):

NPlot is a free charting library for .NET which should handle what you are looking for (and a whole lot more). It'll handle the resize for you automatically when set up properly. Go [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nplot/) for the download and [here](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/index.php?n=Main.Examples) are some examples of what it can do.  The download itself also comes with a few tutorial projects demonstrating what it can do.

Simply add a reference to the NPlot.dll from your project and then add a PlotSurface2D to your form. Set the `AutoScaleAutoGeneratedAxes` property of your plot to true

```
plotSurface.AutoScaleAutoGeneratedAxes = true;
```

then each time you add a new data point to the plotSurface, the axis will automatically resize for you.

Comment: sounds like a winner, i'll try it out and give it a go

Comment: According to the xml comment, the autosizing only applies when the plot is added to the surface, not when the surface is refreshed. In order to get the auto sizing to work I had to remove and re-add a plot.